# Trying to convert a integer into a ACGT DNA sequence

Tags: python, dna-sequence

I am trying to reverse my stringtobin function so that when I run bintostring([3]) it will return "AAAT" where A=0,C=1,G=2,T=3, for example CCCC will return 85 because (1 * 64) + (1 * 16) + (1 * 4) + (1 * 1) = 85. My bintostring function now just returns an empty string.

```
dna = {'A':0, 'C':1, 'G':2, 'T':3}
dna2 = {0:'A', 1:'C', 2:'G', 3:'T'}

def bintostring(num):
    seq = []
    nums = [64,16,4,1]
    #main while
    i = 0
    while i<len(num):
        #nums while (iterate through nums)
        k = 0
        while k<len(nums):
            #dna2 while (iterate through dna2)
            x = 0
            while x<len(dna2):
                check = 0
                if num[i]//nums[k] == dna2[x]:
                    seq.append(dna2[x])
                    check+=1
                elif check>0:
                    seq.append('A')
                x+=1
            k+=1
        i+=1
    return("".join(seq))

print(bintostring([3]))

def stringtobin(seq):
    power_of_4 = 1
    num = 0
    if len(seq)!=4: return None
    i = len(seq)-1
    while i>=0:
        power_of_4*=4
        Digitval = dna[seq[i]]
        num+=Digitval*power_of_4//4
        i-=1
    return num

print(stringtobin("AAAT"))
```

Comment: I don't get why ```bintostring([3]) it will return "AAAT"``` should be true. You give a list with 1 element (3) into the function

Comment: `if  num[i]//nums[k] == x:` will work

Comment: Do you mean each pair of bits should encode one of these values, and the encoded result is always one byte? Please [edit] to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Your encoding is in base 4 which can't hold the length information of your sequence.

Without the length information the encoded value 3 could mean T or TA or TAAA or TAAAA... (there would be no way to know).

If the sequences are always 4 letters long (or the length is stored/provided separately), you can implement the functions like this

```
def stringToBin(S):
    return sum( 4**i*"ACGT".index(p) for i,p in enumerate(S))

def binToString(N,size=4):
    result = ""
    for _ in range(size):
        N,p = divmod(N,4)
        result += "ACGT"[p]
    return result

print(stringToBin("AAAT")) # 192
print(binToString(192))    # AAAT

print(stringToBin("TA"))   # 3
print(stringToBin("TAAA")) # 3
print(binToString(3))      # TAAA
print(binToString(3,2))    # TA    (length has to be supplied separately)
```

If you want your numeric encoding to also carry the length information, you should make it base 5 and use a non-zero value for each letter.  This way, TA and TAAA would give different numbers.

```
def stringToBin(S):
    return sum( 5**i*" ACGT".index(p) for i,p in enumerate(S))

def binToString(N):
    result = ""
    while N:
        N,p = divmod(N,5)
        result += " ACGT"[p]
    return result

print(stringToBin("TA"))   # 9
print(stringToBin("TAAA")) # 159
print(binToString(9))      # TA        
print(binToString(159))    # TAAA
```

*Obviously this produces larger number so, a 32 bit unsigned integer will only hold 13 letters as opposed to 16 in base 4. If you're doing this to reduce the size of storage, using text compression (e.g. zip) will probably be more efficient than converting to a fixed base binary representation*

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt seems inordinately complex. Just map the bottom two bits to a value, then shift them off.

```py
def bintostring(num):
    seq = []
    for n in num:
        subseq = []
        for b in range(4):
            subseq.append(dna2[n & 3])
            n >>= 2
        seq.append("".join(reversed(subseq)))
    return seq
```

In case it's not obvious, `&` is bitwise AND; `value & 3` obtains the bottom two bits of `value`.

The `stringtobin` function could be similarly simplified. Demo: https://ideone.com/RlzegN